# Use languageUtil in liferay 7.2 themes?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have an old theme that often uses the `languageUtil` like this:

```
<span>${languageUtil.get(locale, "header-contact")}</span>
```

I also have a Language.properties that sets all these keys. On the liferay tutorials I only found that you simply need to put the properties files in the `src/main/resources/content/` folder of a module to make it my language module. Apparently liferay detects this automatically and loads it in.

For me this did not work and liferay only displays `header-contact` instead of the translation. I am using CE 7.2

Comment: hm got to confess that im not a theme expert . but if the resulting war will be converted to a wab .. may be...  provide corresponding capability like in https://github.com/andrebiegel/liferay-configuration-api .. like ..."liferay.resource.bundle".... may be @olafk knows more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `<@liferay.language key="header-contact" />` in your theme instead and deploy a @Component with `service = ResourceBundle.class`. In your ResourceBundle Component you could provide your translation using a ResourceBundle. Maybe this article might help here [Language Keys ResourceBundle](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/overriding-language-keys)

Comment: thank you, it actually worked. If I understand it correctly I have to specify the language this resource bundle is for, right? Do I have to extend the ResourceBundle class for every language I want to support or is there a easier way?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not figure this one out correctly. In my scenario, it ended with a resourcebundle component per supported language. Each having a different property such as `property = "language.id=en_GB"` - but I am open if there are any improvement to this. Using this approach, your language keys are kind of global and you could use theme from all of your bundles